# Does it make sense to say that change is just what is changing?

Tags: change

Does it make sense to say that change is just what is changing? If so, which philosopher or philosophers have claimed it?

If no-one goes as far as to say so, then what could change be in addition to what is changing, and how could those alternatives be ruled out?

I'm asking because if "now" is a changing indivisible instant then its changes would also be indivisible, which would surely complicate Zeno's paradoxes of movement.

> The concept of an indivisible is closely allied to, but to be
>   distinguished from, that of an [infinitesimal](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/). An indivisible is, by
>   definition, something that cannot be divided, which is usually
>   understood to mean that it has no proper parts.

Comment: can i have some feedback on the downvote. it's an exploratory question, like many others that have been asked by many others. i don't see any mistake, or how i can find the answer with further research, or any lack of clarity

Comment: What does it mean "is s changing indivisible instant" ?

Comment: which word don't you understand? do i need to find someone who says that "now" is indivisible :) ? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: See e.g. [Change, Cause, Time, Motion](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/change/#ChaCauTimMot) : "The thesis that time could pass without change in anything at all has proved controversial, and we have adopted the usage that change in a thing implies the passage of time." Thus, it seems that we "perceive" change comparing the state of something in two different instants of time.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA are you suggesting that means change is what is changing? if so, i'm a little unsure that you are right!

Comment: i mean close, but not trivial imvho @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: You'll find that there is no notion of time and change that makes sense once we reify either in metaphysics. The idea of a 'changing indivisible instant' doesn't fly because things would only be able to change between instants.

Comment: @PeterJ not sure where you're heading there

Comment: Given an indivisible instant, how can change be happening?  If my hand moves from point A to point B in an instant, then there must be an instant when it's in between, and we've divided that instant.  I understand "changing", "indivisible", and :"instant" as words well enough, but the same is true of "colorless", "green", "ideas", "sleep", and "furiously"- or for that matter "four-sided" and "triangle".

Comment: The usual answer to this is to refer to 'entropy'. Build a sand castle. From the moment you've completed it.. it begins returning to a level beach. Entropy and time are related (in a closed system). Change is factored into the universe.

Comment: @confused I don't think that your discussion accurately describes the question. I recommend rephrasing the question.

Comment: @confused - I was suggesting that your question raises a deep issue about change and time, as David indicates above, meaning that there may be no straightforward answer. .

Comment: the question is what i meant to ask @MarkAndrews

Comment: not sure what's unclear, can someone state what they find unclear please?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn’t seem to make sense to say that change is just what is changing. One way to see this, is that if change were just what is changing, there could be only one change per thing. Nothing could have changed more than once. Because, suppose a thing Th1 changed twice, the changes being Ch1 and Ch2. But

change is just what is changing, and therefore

Ch1 = Th1

but also: change is just what is changing, and therefore

Ch2 = Th1

and from the transitivity of identity, we get

Ch1 = Ch2

In other words, all changes for a given thing are identical. So, a given thing can have only one change, that is to change only once.

Comment: is there a word for that -- things only changing once?

Comment: @confused good question

Comment: @confused Somehow this reminded me Aquinas's God, whose essence is his existence, which is an act of being, and Hegel's Spirit, whose nature is "*to be this absolute liveliness, this process... being itself only as it comes to itself as such a product of itself; its actuality being merely that it has made itself into what it is*". You can probably even get out of Ram's reductio by denying that a changing thing can be identical to itself, or anything else, as it is everchanging and is the change itself. But many question that Hegel makes sense on this.